# Relational Interpretation of Quantum Mechanics and Universal Wave Function

Tags: quantum-interpretations

Why is there no universal wave function for a relational interpretation of quantum mechanics?

"Quantum mechanics is a theory about the physical description of physical systems relative to other systems, and this is a complete description of the world" - Carlo Rovelli (from wikipedia! :p )

Basically, if the Universe functions functions in a relative manner when seen in part, how does it function in a relative manner when seen as a whole, when there are no "other systems"?

Comment: you might want to read this this and make a more specific question: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_wavefunction

Answer (score 1):

There is no universal wave function. The universe has many different mathematical descriptions, each corresponding to what a different observer can interact with around them. Each is incomplete, because no observer can interact with whole universe. Each observer, for example excludes themselves from the world they interact with.

Comment: Ok, but if the universe is flat (as the local geometry seems to be), and space is infinite, wouldn't each observer, over all time and probability, view each possible event from every possible frame of reference? This would mean the Universe is not deterministic in the sense of a guiding wave function, but a guiding probability function.. isn't that effectively the same thing anyway?